# Find combinations of list indexes where all values in between are smaller

Tags: algorithm, combinations

There is a list that can have any number of elements in it. I need to find all the combinations of indexes i,j in the list, where no number between i and j can be larger than the Min(i,j)

Examples: list = [1,2,5,6,4]
Combinations: (1,2), (1,5), (2,5), (5,6)

The easiest way is to run through each index and check with every number after it, but that becomes very slow with a large dataset. Can someone help me come up with an efficient solution?

Comment: Are you really talking about indexes, not list items, when describing the requirements based on `i` and `j`? Also, are you asking the same question as is being asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70902589/find-number-of-contiguous-subarrays-with-all-intermediate-numbers-less-than-the)?

Comment: I am talking about the list items when talking about i and j. Yes that problem is similar.

Comment: Similar or the same? What is the difference?

Comment: Why is (1,5) a solution? 2 is larger than min(1; 5) = 1. With using maximum instead (1,6) and (2,6) would also be valid.